# How to hide or disable the columns block options (number of columns & stack on mobile)?

Tags: block-editor

I use a columns block in a block pattern that I want users to be able to insert anywhere in a post. I want the editor to be able to insert the pattern and edit the content but I don't want them to be able to change the number of columns or change the setting to 'stack on mobile'.

How can I hide these options from the editor completely?

[image]